# How can I make all the EventListeners in this page to work?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

```
var btnAdaugaPrajeala = document.getElementById('adaugaPrajeala');
var btnClosePrajeala = document.getElementById('closeAdaugaPrajeli');
var modalPrajeala = document.getElementById('mdl-prajeli');




btnAdaugaPrajeala.addEventListener('click', function(){
modalPrajeala.classList.add('active-modal');
});
btnClosePrajeala.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modalPrajeala.classList.remove('active-modal');
});


var btnAdauga = document.getElementById('adaugaSortiment');
var btnCloseAdauga = document.getElementById('closeAdauga');
var modalSortiment = document.getElementById('mdl-sortimente');

btnAdauga.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modalSortiment.classList.add('active-modal');
});
btnCloseAdauga.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modalSortiment.classList.remove('active-modal');
});
```

I know it's not a really dry code, I tried to do this for the sake of this post. 
I can't wrap my head around this issue - the 3rd and 4th event listeners are not working. 
I tried to swap them and it seems that only the first 2 are working, any ideas?

Comment: Is there an error in the console?? It is nearly impossible to help you with what you provided.

Comment: It actually says - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, at this line " btnAdauga.addEventListener('click', function(){"

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newcomer, and I did not find an answer to this.
It's weird that if I swap the declarations and functions between them, always, the first half works.

Comment: There you go, it can't find the element. btnAdauga is null

Comment: It still works tho, if it's in the first half.

Comment: Well that one finds the button...... Again, no clue why it is not finding the button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: I guess that might be an issue, however, that button works if it's the first one declared, if the other pack of 3 declarations and functions are first, those one are working.

Comment: followed the link, first option worked like a charm, thank youuu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: it was actually a really stupid mistake, my bad. I just moved the scripts and got it to work, as in the link provided by epascarello.